# Sum of derivative of digamma function and its limit

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

It seems that the limit
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}\Psi'(ka) - \frac{1}{a}\Psi(na)\right)
$$
exists for $a>0$, but I don't have any idea to compute this. Is there any simple form of this limit?

EDIT : as some people commented, I added additional constant $\frac{1}{a}$ which makes the limit converges for all $a>0$. Also, I can show that the limit function $f(a)$ satisfies a functional equation 
$$
f(a) = f(a+1) + \frac{1}{(a+1)^{2}}f\left(\frac{a}{a+1}\right) - \frac{\ln(a+1)}{a(a+1)}.
$$

Comment: As pointed out by JJacquelin, the limit does not exist unless $a=1$ but instead $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \left( \sum_{k=1} \psi’(ka) -\frac{1}{a}\psi(na)\right)$$ converge. This can be easily deduced from the following simple observation: if $f:[1,\infty)\to[0,\infty)$ is monotone decreasing, then $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\int_{1}^{n} f(x)\,dx-\sum_{k=1}^{n}f(k)\right)$$ converges.

Comment: @SangchulLee Yes I just edited, thank you. However, I need a closed formula of the limit, or integral representation of it. I can show that the limit satisfies some interesting functional equation (this follows from the other context) but I don't know if we can derive closed formula from this equation.

Comment: Not sure about its closed form, but we can write $$f(a)=\frac{\gamma}{a}+\int_{0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{t}{1-e^{-t}}-1\right)\frac{dt}{e^{at}-1}.$$

Comment: @SangchulLee That might be helpful. Thanks! Does it obvious that the function satisfies the functional equation?